# Compress all file .js with Google Closure Compiler Application in one File

Tags: javascript, compression, google-closure-compiler

I would like to Compress all my file `.js` in a same directory in one file with Google Closure Compiler in a command line.

For one file it's :

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js test.js --js_output_file final.js
```

But I didn't find in the doc how put my other file at the end of `final.js` without write over the last compress file ?

I would like something like that :

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js --option *.js --js_output_file final.js
```

It's possible or must I do a programm who add all file in a file and after compress it ?
Thank you if you can help me !

Comment: By the way, I wrote a script to do it. I recommend you do the same.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
java -jar path/to/closure-compiler/build/compiler.jar \ 
--js input_one.js \ 
--js input_two.js \ 
... \ 
--js_output_file compiled_output.js
```

Comment: this is what I get when using the jar like this !

Answer (score 7):

I tried Orbits' answer, but It didn't really work perhaps the version I use is a newer version. The command I use is :

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js file1.js file2.js file3.js  --js_output_file --js_output_file compiled_output.js.
```

Comment: I've used this


`java -jar lib/compiler.jar --js \`find ./src/*.js\` --js_output_file build/out.cjs`

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that you’ve installed the Closure Compiler with Homebrew on a Mac, you can also concatenate all files and then pipe them to to Closure (this should also work the `java -jar` way, but I haven’t verified it):

```
cat $(ls scripts/*.js) | closure-compiler --js_output_file main.js
```

Comment: `ls scripts/*.js` does not recurse through sub-folders

Answer (score 3):

Here are five globbing techniques for including multiple input files, with documentation extracted from the [`CommandLineRunner`](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/blob/master/src/com/google/javascript/jscomp/CommandLineRunner.java) class:

---

**(1)** This is a variation of [muka's technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4043402#comment25381287_13916065), removing the `--js` flag, which is not needed:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js_output_file build/out.js `find ./src/*.js`
```

From the docs:

> The `--js` flag name is optional, because args are interpreted as files by default.

This will include all `.js` files in `/src/`, but won't include any files in subdirectories of `/src/`.

---

**(2)** Similar to **1**, but will include all `.js` files in `/src/` *and all its subdirectories*:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js_output_file build/out.js `find ./src/ -name '*.js'`
```

---

**(3)** Similar to **2**, but uses `xargs`:

```
find ./src/ -name '*.js' \
    | xargs java -jar compiler.jar \
                --js_output_file build/out.js \
                --manage_closure_dependencies
```

From the docs:

> It is convenient to leverage the additional arguments feature when using the
>   Closure Compiler in combination with `find` and `xargs`:
>
> ```
> find MY_JS_SRC_DIR -name '*.js' \
>     | xargs java -jar compiler.jar --manage_closure_dependencies
> ```
>
> The `find` command will produce a list of '*.js' source files in
>   the `MY_JS_SRC_DIR` directory while `xargs` will convert them
>   to a single, space-delimited set of arguments that are appended to the
>   `java` command to run the Compiler.
>
> Note that it is important to use the
>   `--manage_closure_dependencies` option in this case because the
>   order produced by `find` is unlikely to be sorted correctly with
>   respect to `goog.provide()` and `goog.requires()`.

---

**(4)** The [v20140625](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/releases/tag/v20140625)
release added support for the `**` (globstar) wildcard, which recursively
matches all subdirectories.

For example, this will include all `.js` files in `/src/` and all its subdirectories:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js_output_file build/out.js './src/**.js'
```

More info [here](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/pull/454). From the docs:

> You may also use minimatch-style glob patterns. For example, use:
>
> ```
> --js='**.js' --js='!**_test.js'
> ```
>
> to recursively include all js files that do not end in _test.js

From the [Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileSystem.html#getPathMatcher(java.lang.String)):

> The following rules are used to interpret glob patterns:
>
> - The `*` character matches zero or more characters of a name component without crossing directory boundaries.
> - The `**` characters matches zero or more characters crossing directory boundaries.

---

**(5)** The [v20140625](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/releases/tag/v20140625)
release also added a new feature: if the input path is a directory, then all `.js` files
in that directory and all subdirectories will be included.

For example, this will include all `.js` files in `/src/` and all its subdirectories:

```
java -jar compiler.jar \
    --js_output_file build/out.js './src/'
```

More info [here](https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/pull/454).

Answer (score 2):

You can use KjsCompiler: https://github.com/knyga/kjscompiler
. Compiles multiple JavaScript files with Google Closure Compiler application in a right order

How to solve your problem:
1. Add annotations to js files, like this:

`/**
* @depends {lib/somefile.js}
**/`
If you do not care about compilation chain, you can ignore this step.
2. `java -jar kjscompile.jar`

You can look for example here: https://github.com/knyga/kjscompiler/tree/master/examples

Answer (score 1):

```
    <exec executable="java">
        <arg line="-jar ../lib/compiler.jar --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --language_in ECMASCRIPT5 --js_output_file=${compressdir}/js/controllers/jscontrollersfiles.js ${webappdir}/js/controllers/*.js" />
    </exec>
```

Comment: Here compresseddir is a directory which contains compressed js files and

Comment: and webdir refers upto webapp in our project

Answer (score 0):

The github of google closure doc gives the below command.

If you have multiple scripts, you should compile them all together with one compile command.

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js_output_file=out.js in1.js in2.js in3.js ...
```

---

You can also use minimatch-style globs.

```
# Recursively include all js files in subdirs
java -jar compiler.jar --js_output_file=out.js 'src/**.js'

# Recursively include all js files in subdirs, excluding test files.
# Use single-quotes, so that bash doesn't try to expand the '!'
java -jar compiler.jar --js_output_file=out.js 'src/**.js' '!**_test.js'
```

Source : https://github.com/google/closure-compiler#compiling-multiple-scripts

Comment: **Do not** forget the simple quotes. I end loosing time because of this. Without them, it works on windows; not on linux.