# compress all js in a folder to new folder useing google closure compiler?

Tags: google-closure-compiler

**how can i compress all my js in a folder to a new folder** ?

i have search around google and stackoverflow, what i found is just
[Compress all file .js with Google Closure Compiler Application in one File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043402/compress-all-file-js-with-google-closure-compiler-application-in-one-file)
that puting it all to one.. + can we put a wildcard or something?

so i can do something like

```
java -jar bin/compiler.jar ../../path/my/*.js --js_output_file ../../path/new/*.js
```

thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Comment: Simple mode or advanced mode?  For advanced mode, it always comes out into one single file, but you can turn on the file-boundary markers so that you can manually cut the output file back into pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash scripting to the rescue. Something like

```
files=`find ../../path/my -name "*.js"`
for i in $files;
do
    java -jar bin/compiler.jar $i --js_output_file `dirname $i`../new/$i.js
done
```

(not tested)

Comment: i get the point, but im not good in bash. i got an error line 2 syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r'' `for i in $files;

Comment: for i in $files; do echo $i; done work with no enter, i wonder why

Answer (score 1):

I've got a bash script on gitub for this, https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/compile-js

works like this

compile-js build ../../path/new/output.min.js ../../path/my/*