# Closure Compiler -- Include ALL .js files in directory

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Is there anyway to include all *.js files in a directory to be combined and minified using Google's Closure Compiler?

The only way I know of is listing each file individually:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js 1.js --js 2.js  --js_output_file app-min.js
```

but in an enterprise app, this is not feasible.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler uses java style globs:

- `--js src/*.js` - all js files in the src folder
- `--js src/**.js` - all js files in the src folder and any sub folders (recursive)
- `--js !src/**test.js` - exclude files that end in with "test.js" (recursive)

Order matters.

However, you will need some method to determine the correct order. See https://github.com/google/closure-compiler/wiki/Manage-Closure-Dependencies

Comment: this works. but now i need to figure out how to EXCLUDE some files from that directory... I shoudlve been more clear with my question.

Comment: What about `--js controller/**/*.js`. I excpected it to take all js file under controller AND all other of it sub floders; no matter how deep. It works fine on windows, but on linux only files under a direct subfolder of controller are taken like if I wrot `--js controller/*/*.js `

Comment: Ok, I found out you **should not** forget the simple quotes. I end uploosing time because of this. Without them, it works on windows; not on linux.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question has been previously ask, please see this post

[Compress all file .js with Google Closure Compiler Application in one File](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4043402/compress-all-file-js-with-google-closure-compiler-application-in-one-file)

But you might want to be careful with any method that auto-appends files in a directory and send them off to the Closure compiler, so the right order for compilation of your scripts is maintained

Comment: I thought it was a duplicate as well, but after reading it - it's not.